# How to ignore //NOSONAR during scan?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have to do an audit of the Sonar issues in my project that have been suppressed with `//NOSONAR`.

Is there a way to do a scan that *ignores* the directive so that I can see which violations have been suppressed?

Comment: I think it's not configurable. You could use command line tools or your IDE to globally replace `NOSONAR` with `SONAR` (or whatever) then run your build, then throw away the replacement changes

Comment: It's a pity that it's not configurable. There should be a rule "Unneccessary use of `//NOSONAR`" that raises an issue when there's no issue at this place without the `//NOSONAR` - no-one will ever remove a `//NOSONAR` just to test if the former false-positive is gone after the ruleset or plugin was updated.

Comment: @outofmind great point but even if it was was configurable it will be difficult to identify unnecessary use. A separate rule to flag unnecessary use that you mention is required.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I guess `//NOSONAR` works that if it finds an issue it get's ignored when there's a `//NOSONAR` comment, so that rule should be quite easy to implement - but maybe I'm wrong - guess we should put this kind of request at some more prominent place at Google groups or something like that. And I'm quite sure, that unlike other rules this would be one that has to be implemented by the scanner, not within a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of SonarQube language plugins provide a built-in rule to track `NOSONAR` usage:

> "NOSONAR" should not be used to switch off issues - This rule raises an issue when NOSONAR is used.

(see [Java example](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3ANoSonar) or [list of equivalent rule](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#q=nosonar) for other languages)

Enabling this rule in the relevant Quality Profiles will let you continuously track `NOSONAR` usage (and potentially take in into account in your Quality Gate).

As for getting details on the actual issues that were suppressed, no there is no way to *ignore* a directive that is precisely made to *ignore* issues.. As [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) suggested you're better off running an ad-hoc analysis with the `NOSONAR` flags removed and see which new issues get raised (avoid doing that on the existing SonarQube project to not add noise to its history).

Comment: Thanks. There is no *inherent* reason the directive made to ignore issues cannot itself be ignored, but that seems to be the current status. I was planning to use a different branch name to preserve history.